# assign jQuery plugins to html elements its loading, not on window.onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, slider

I have a [one-page web portfolio](http://www.gjh.sk/~ambrus/emental/), where each project's photos is presented in an image carousel  with controls/animation assigned through a jQuery [Lemmon Slider](http://jquery.lemmonjuice.com/plugins/slider-variable-widths.php) plugin. This plugin requires its initialization on `window.onload`.

However, since the images are relatively big (and there are more projects on the page) and the `window.onload` event is not triggered until all of the images are downloaded, the carousel is unusable until that event fires (curently ~5seconds with a broadband connection).

So the question is - **how could i force calling the plugin on the carousel** (while lazy-loading the images), or **how could i show a loading spinner gif while loading the images and the controls in the background and display them (with assigned plugin controls) when they're ready?**

the pseudo code for the relevant part of my index.php goes something like this:

```
- for every directory in 'projects/':
    - read the directory
    - generate the carousel and put all the images in the code <div> <ul> <li> <img>
    - assign this project's carousel ID
- at the end of the page, initialize the plugin for every carousel there is through the window.onload event
```

I hope I provided all the info needed to help me; I'm eagerly awaiting any answer.

Comment: Just put a visible spinner gif on your page (maybe with a data uri, so it doesn't need to load as well). In the body.onload, hide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, In case what you meant is that plugin must be initialize when the page loads, but not necessarily by onload event, you can try jquery "ready"
So say that your spinning gif has id "spinning",
you can do

```
$("#spinning").ready(function(){
    $(this).show();
});
$(".carousel").ready(function(){
    $("#spinning").hide();
});
```

And put this "spinning" element outside the carousel (not as child), probably just under body or a div outside carousel and make it absolutely positioned in the center of carousel.

This way, as soon as spinning element is ready (of course before heavy carousel is ready), it will show up and spins. Once the carousel ready, the gif will stop spinning and disappear.

note: document.ready is executed once document is ready, and .ready is executed once that element is ready. In contrast, window.onload is executed after all elements are ready. So, ready first, than onload. That is the order.

Comment: thanks, this logic works. however, the plugin i use for the image slider needs to have the images' dimensions so it can function properly, and therefore the `.ready` event is too soon for the carousel. I have solved this using [the ImagesLoaded jQuery plugin](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)